# Stream OpenCV mat data with C++

Tags: c++, video-streaming, opencv3.0

I 'm currently working with object detection in a Linux machine without display (with OpenCV and C++). I need to stream OpenCV output data (mat) to other machine (Linux/Windows/Android) to display as live video. Of course, i want compression (not raw CV mat data).
Any suggestion for implementation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to transfer data via TCP.

You had better use a thread to send `VIDEO_DATA` or it will affect the process that OpenCV grab next frame of images. You can add some algorithms of image compression before you send. The codes show below:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

std::string IP_ADDR {"123.45.67.89"};
int PORT = 6666;
std::atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

void *tcp_thread_graph(void *arg) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd == -1) { throw; }

    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_ADDR.c_str());
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    int err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    while(flag.test_and_set()) {
        //TODO: add compression algorithm before sending
        send(sockfd, (char*)VIDEO_DATA, sizeof(VIDEO_DATA), 0);
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used UDP for streaming frame, each frame will be converted from cv Mat to image to reduce size, on receiver - data will be decoded back to cv Mat to display. Compression ratio is about 10x, seems to fit my requirement